# Disable Windows search history

Tags: windows-10, search, privacy, history

How can I disable Windows search history?

[image: Screenshot]

I disabled "My device history" and "cleared my device history" from Windows Permission & History settings. All data collection settings from Windows privacy settings are disabled, yet it still remembers my search history.

It seems that there's no option to disable it. Just to add more clarification to the solution. Here are the steps for scheduling a cleaning task: *Task scheduler* -> *Create task*. Name it, select Run with highest privileges and choose the trigger (e.g. on startup). Now in the actions add an action and fill in the following:

1. Program/script: `powershell.exe`
2. Add arguments: `Remove-Item -Path 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\WordWheelQuery\*'`

Note: For me, it didn't work without removing the asterisk at the end of the command.

Comment: You can’t disable it entirely, you can clear the history, in theory you could write a script the deleted the key when you restart I guess.  What type of solution are you looking for since it’s not possible to disable the File Explorer search history?

Comment: First, I'd like to make sure it's not possible.
If this is indeed the case, then the question would be how to write a script to clear it on restart.

Comment: It is absolutely is not possible to disable the File Explorer Search History, but it is trivial, to clear the search history.  This can be done through the UI by clicking `Clear Search History` or by the removal of a specific registry key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Yet, it still remembers my search history.

File Explorer search history cannot be disabled but it can be cleared.  After performing a search you can easily clear your search history through the UI.

> [image]

If you are attempting to automate this functionality you will have to write a script to delete the following registry key.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\WordWheelQuery
```

I absolutely would test this script before you implement it but something as simple as the following PowerShell command.

```
Remove-Item -Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\WordWheelQuery\*"
```

The simplest solution would be to create a Scheduled Task, that runs a PowerShell script when the user logs out of the computer, this would clear the recent search history.

Source: [How to Delete the Search History in Windows File Explorer](https://www.howtogeek.com/282281/how-to-delete-the-search-history-in-windows-file-explorer/)